# SQL Query Optimization Issue with OFFSET and CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am trying to figure out what is going wrong here. Basically if I remove the "CLEAR = 0" from the codeblock below, my query turns into 50ms read. With it still in, the duration is 2.1 seconds.

Indexes on the [Alerts] table don't seem to be helping either. I am quite lost on why one additional AND clause in an existing WHERE is destroying the query.

```
WITH TempResult AS(
     SELECT Table1.*, p.* FROM Table1
     CROSS APPLY(
          SELECT (CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) = SUM(Alerts.ACK+0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACK,
               MIN(Alerts.Visited+0) AS VisitedAlert FROM Alerts
          INNER JOIN AlertRecipients on Alerts.Id = AlertRecipients.AlertID
               AND AlertRecipients.UserID = @userID 
          WHERE Table1.Id = Alerts.Table1ID AND Alerts.[CLEAR] = 0
     ) p WHERE VisitedAlert IS NOT NULL
), TempCount AS ( 
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
)
SELECT * FROM TempResult, TempCount 
ORDER BY cast(STUFF(VID, 1, 1, '') as int) Desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 14 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Have you compared the query plans?

Comment: I have compared query plans and it gives the exact same Query Cost on the same parts, 58% Clustered Index Scan on Table1.Id and 31% on the sort.

Comment: I strongly doubt it's the exact same query plan.  Please could you use the following website to share the plans?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Here is the plan for the fast Query without "Alerts.[Clear]=0": https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1uyFb2vG

                                  Here is the one with "Alerts.[Clear]=0": 
 https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJMUF-2vM

Comment: It seems to be multiplying heavily with the number of rows in [AlertRecipients]. When I went from 157 rows to 66 in [AlertRecipients], the time went from 2.2 seconds down to 1 second. And when I queried it with 3 rows in [AlertRecipients], the time went to 600ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my apparently poorly written initial query. I guess these things are just read pretty differently by SQL optimizer.

```
WITH TempResult AS(
SELECT p.* FROM 
(Select Table1.Id, Table1.PeopleID,
    (CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) = SUM(Alerts.ACK+0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AllACKed, MIN(Alerts.Visited+0) AS VisitedAlert FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Alerts AS Alerts
          INNER JOIN AlertRecipients AS AlertRecipients on AlertRecipients.AlertID = Alerts.Id AND AlertRecipients.UserID = @userID
    on Alerts.Table1ID = Table1.Id AND Alerts.[CLEAR] = 0
          GROUP BY Table1.Id, Table1.PeopleID
     ) p WHERE (<'any user given filter on p'>)
), TempCount AS ( 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
)
SELECT * FROM TempResult, TempCount ORDER BY Id Desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```